# Test for uniformity in R

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, uniform-distribution, dice

i am searching for a test for uniformity in R.

`ks.test(x,'punif')` looks quite good, but my data has only 6 different values (results of rolling a die) which leads to a lot of ties in the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I read that i only can ignore this if the number of ties is small in comparison to the whole sample.

Is there a better test?

Comment: Consider looking at this answer by Ilmari Karonen: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70802/how-can-i-test-whether-a-die-is-fair  He does not appear to present `R` code, but you can try to implement his suggestions in `R` and edit your question with your own `R` code if you have trouble.

Comment: thank you!
Just to make sure i am right:

`pchisq(sum(((table(X)-N/6)^2)/N*6),5)`

where X is a vector of dice results and N is the length of the vector

Comment: I do not really have time now to check whether you have done it correctly.  I suggest looking for a worked example either on the internet or in a textbook and comparing the answer your code gives with the known correct answer provided in the worked example.  Probably search for `'fair die' test example`, etc.  If you cannot get the correct answer then post your code above in your question along with the correct answer.

Comment: Here is `R` code to test whether a die is fair: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578932/fair-die-or-not-from-3d-printer/1580703

Comment: The chi-square test immediately comes to mind.  It will be applicable and easy to compute whenever you have more than 30 observations (that is, an expectation of five or more observations per possible value).  For smaller numbers it's wise to simulate the sampling distribution of this statistic.

Answer (score 3):

Per [whuber's comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257681/test-for-uniformity-in-r#comment696648_257681), the standard way to test for a particular discrete distribution (e.g., a uniform one - but also any other one) is [the Pearson chi squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test). In R, use `chisq.test()`. A simulation:

```
> set.seed(1)
> rolls <- sample(1:6,10,replace=TRUE)
> chisq.test(rbind(table(factor(rolls,levels=1:6)),rep(length(rolls),6)/6))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rbind(table(factor(rolls, levels = 1:6)), rep(length(rolls),     6)/6)
X-squared = 0.94156, df = 5, p-value = 0.9671
```

You will get a warning that the p value may be incorrect because we have a small sample size (as a rule of thumb, the approximation used here works if each number is expected to come up at least five times). In such a case, you can instead use a simulation for the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. Just use `simulate.p.value=TRUE` (and possibly increase the number of Monte Carlo draws from the default of 2,000 using the `B` parameter).

Comment: I do not think the answer is fully correct. This is a goodness of fit test as the expected values are known beforehand:  the call to function `chisq.test` should use argument `p` for the expected probabilities of each outcome. So instead of `chisq.test(rbind(table(values), expected_counts))` use `chisq.test(x = table(values), p = expected_probabilites)` . If you compare the approaches, you will see that the chi-square statistic is different. The help also explains that when using `simulate.p.value` the procedure differs between goodness of fit and contingency table.

Comment: A simple example that shows the chi-square statistic differs (and if you use `simulate.p.value` for cases with large numbers of categories, you can also notice the difference in speed). The first call is the contingency table case, the second is the goodness of fit. `x <- sample(1:6, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(1, 6));`
`y <- rep(length(x), 6)/6;` `chisq.test(rbind(table(x), y));` `chisq.test(table(x), p = rep(1/6, 6))`.   The answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580703 , linked above, actually uses a goodness of fit test.